# Google Analytics: events triggered different than pageviews

Tags: google-analytics

I am firing an event for all pages located in the /articles directory of a site I am developing. It appears to be working but I am seeing a huge discrepancy between events fired total and page views total within said directory. Can anyone explain why this is happening?

Thanks, 
Clint

Comment: Can you provide any more information about the details of your configuration and what "huge discrepancy" means?

Comment: I have a standard implementation of google analytics tracking pageviews and trigger the event using the following on document ready:

ga('send','event', 'Section', '{{ object.category }}', '{{ object.title }}');

the difference between events and page views is roughly 40,000 page views to 25,000 events.